# can't initialize MySQL library

Tags: c++, mysql, embedded-database

when i try to run a simple program like this:

```
int main(void) {
    mysql_library_init(0, NULL, NULL);
    mysql_library_end();
    return 0;}
```

i get the following output errors:

> mysql_embedded: Can't find file: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
>   2015-12-30 00:23:04 7fd31a6be740  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
>   InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
>   InnoDB: the directory.
>   mysql_embedded: File '/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

here is some info about the directory and files:

```
$ ls -l --time-style=long-iso /var/lib/
...
drwx------ 4 mysql         mysql          4096 2015-12-26 12:58 mysql
...

$ sudo ls -l --time-style=long-iso /var/lib/mysql/mysql/plugin.frm 
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 8586 2015-12-25 21:49 /var/lib/mysql/mysql/plugin.frm
$ sudo ls -l --time-style=long-iso /var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 56 2015-12-25 21:49 /var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf
```

what's the problem?

```
$ dpkg -s libmysqld-dev | grep 'Version'
Version: 5.6.27-0ubuntu1
```

Comment: Which user are you using, and which group is that user a member of?

Comment: which user am i using where? excuse me, but i don't understand what you're asking about.